# Netty Correlating Request and Responses

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I want to write a proxy for a TCP binary protocol. I’m using the HexDump example in Netty’s repo as a guide.
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy

This works fine. But I sometimes **want to modify the response based on the original request**.

Looking around it seems that using the inbound channels AttributeMap could be the place to store such request details. (Some more details below)

```
io.netty.util.AttributeMap
```

But while it sort of works **sometimes one request overwrites the details of another request**.

This makes sense, Netty is asynchronous and you can’t really guarantee when somethings going to happen.

So I was wondering **how can I reliably correlate each request with is response**. Note I can’t 
change the protocol, this might have been one way to pass details between request and response.

Thanks for your insight.

**HexDumpFrontendHandler**

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws InterruptedException {
…
ctx.channel().attr(utils.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE).set(requestDetails);
…
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

    // Start the connection attempt.
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
     .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
     .handler(new HexDumpBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
     .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);

    ChannelFuture f = b.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
    outboundChannel = f.channel();
    f.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            // connection complete start to read first data
            inboundChannel.read();
        } else {
            // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
            inboundChannel.close();
        }
    });
}
```

**HexDumpBackendHandler**

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
…
RequestDetails requestDetails = inboundChannel.attr(utils.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE).getAndRemove();
…
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (work around?)  to this was the following. The protocol I was working with couldn't guarantee a unique identifier per request globally but it did uniquely identify request's within a tcp connection.

So the following combination allowed me to create a ConcurrentHashMap with the following as the key
**host + ephemeral port + identifier local to the connection**

This work for my case. I'm sure their other ways to solve it within the Netty framework itself

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have stumbled upon same issue. Can you please help me on how you accessed ephemeral port & local identifier?

Comment: Hi,The idea I was working on was creating a proxy for the Kafka protocol. I've more notes here: https://github.com/caoimhindenais/kafka-proxy
I was able to get address and port information from the ChannelHandlerContext and Kafka  manages the correlationId per connection.
This combination is what I put into a ConcurrentHashMap

See io/proxy/KafkaProxyFrontendHandler.java:99
 `InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress)ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
int port = socketAddress.getPort();
int correlationId = requestHeader.correlationId(); `